# How to add attribute to the widget?

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I found some solution over the internet, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it.

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5260) someone tells me: I composed a simple patch that adds 2 more attributes to the schedule widget: droppable and onDrop. (patch [here](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/attachmentText?id=5260&aid=52600000000&name=droppable_patch.diff&token=siBN6sAc3hXgw-5E0_dYMhDd8f4:1375861891207))

I have schedlue js file exactly like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/schedule/schedule.js?r=6152). How can I make this patch alive in my project?

Comment: Is there anything you have done?

Comment: Well, I've added "droppable: true," into defaults in js. Now I'm struggling with onDrop method - how to get there date and dropped object :/